# I am stuck on this React Testdome question with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

/*This application should allow the user to update their username by inputting a custom value and clicking the button.

The Username component is finished and should not be changed, but the App component is missing parts. Finish the App component so that the Username component displays the inputted text when the button is clicked.

The App component should use the React.useRef Hook to pass the input to the Username component for the input element and for the Username component.

For example, if the user inputs a new username of "John Doe" and clicks the button, the div element with id root should look like this:

Change Username

## John Doe

*/

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

function Username(props) {
  return <h1 ref={props.myref}>some</h1>;
}
function App() {
  function clickHandler() {}

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Change Username</button>
      <input type="text"/>
      <Username />
    </div>
  );
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

document.querySelector("input").value = "John Doe";
document.querySelector("button").click();
setTimeout(() => console.log(document.getElementById("root").innerHTML));
```

## Note : The Username component is finished and should not be changed

Answer (score 0):

You have ref in username component, you need to create and pass it down, that way you will have an ability to change a content of h1 element.

So here is steps to implement this (I wouldn't write a code for you because writing code by yourself is very important for studying):

1. Create ref in app.js and pass it to username component via myref prop.
2. You need to get value of input and here you have two options: The first one is to make it controllable using state, or second option is to use another ref and pass it into your input.
3. In clickHandler, take your input value (from state or from ref that you passed into input), and modify content of h1 using ref that you passed into myref prop into username component

Done!